# How to install DCEVM in Guidewire?

Tags: guidewire, dcevm

I have downloaded DCEVM jar file. Now I want to install this jar to run Gosu queries in my Gudiewire Studio.
Please help me how to install this DCEVM jar in Guidewire Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

DCEVM was first published in June 2010 as a [research paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1890683.1890688). Since then it has been widely used by Guidewire as the preferred VM for development environments. It allows you to Hot Swap (partially reload code changes to classes) without restarting the VM. In a development environment, it can help save a lot of time where a full VM restart can take several minutes. A fork of the original DCEVM is available at http://dcevm.github.io/.

> [The Dynamic Code Evolution Virtual Machine](https://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) (DCE VM) is a modification
> of the Java HotSpot™ VM that allows unlimited redefinition of loaded
> classes at runtime. The current hot-swapping mechanism of the HotSpot™
> VM allows only changing method bodies. Our enhanced VM allows adding
> and removing fields and methods as well as changes to the super types
> of a class.

You can download the suitable installer jar file for your java version and patch your existing JDK by DCEVM. Unfortunately, the only installer available is a jar file and there are caveats to using it.
First of all, you can only patch your JDK if the DCEVM version supports your JDK minor version. A lot of people don't understand this and encounter failures when they try to patch a newer update of Java with the previous version of DCEVM.

[image: DCEVM versions available in Dec 2020]

A key point to note in the image is the available versions of DCEVM. To be able to install it on Java 8, you must have Java with the update 181 installed i.e. your JDK version must equal 8u181. If you installed an update on the JDK and updated it to 8u271 or another version, the patch is not going to work.

Once you have the installer jar downloaded, you must run it with Administrator privileges on Windows for it to work. In Windows, run cmd as Administrator and then navigate to the directory where the jar is downloaded and run:

```
java -jar dcevm-installer.jar
```

For unix based systems you must run:

```
sudo java -jar dcevm-installer.jar
```

This should open a window where you need to select your correct JDK version and then click on the **Replace by DCEVM** button. If done correctly you'll be able to see the status as below:

[image: DCEVM installer]

Answer (score 1):

DCEVM isn't required to run queries in GW Studio. DCEVM enables more capabilities to hotswap (class reloading after compile).

To run queries in GW Studio you only need start server in debug mode, open Gosu Scratchpad (Tools menu or Alt+Shift+S) and use "Run in Debug Process" button in scratchpad

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your reply. But in the Gosu scratch pad, to run queries in debug mode requires DCEVM and this "Run in Debug Process" button is disabled. Could you please let me know how to enable this button.

Comment: Hi. I haven't installed DCEVM, I only start server in debug mode (Bug button in IDE) and when server is in multiuser level button is enabled. I have GW 8.0.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

For version 10.0.3 there actually 2 possible paths to run Guidewire on DCEVM, depending on the version of Java you are using. Those instructions should also work for other versions of GW

For Java 11

1. Visit http://dcevm.github.io/.
2. Click the Java 11 link.
3. Scroll to find the binary for your development platform, and click to download the relevant file, extract the contents of the downloaded file.
4. Add the DCEVM as an alternate JDK in Studio.
5. In Studio, click File → Project Structure
6. Under Platform Settings, click SDKs.
7. Click Add New SDK +.
8. Select the folder for the DCEVM, and then click OK.
9. In the Name text box, change the name to DCEVM.
10. Click OK.
11. Click Run → Edit Configurations.
12. Under Application, click Servers.
13. Next to JRE, click DCEVM.
14. Do not set the DCEVM as your project SDK.

For Java 8

1. Visit http://dcevm.github.io/.
2. Click the link under Binaries to download the appropriate DCEVM installer for your java version.
3. Install the DCEVM as an alternative JVM.
4. At a command prompt, run java -jar installer.jar, where installer.jar is the name of the file you downloaded in the previous step.
   java –jar DCEVM-8u181-installer.jar
5. The Dynamic Code Evolution VM Installer dialog appears.
6. Select the installation directory for the JDK corresponding to the DCEVM version you are installing.
7. Click the Install DCEVM as altjvm button.
8. The Dynamic Code Evolution VM Installer dialog displays Yes in the Installed altjvm column for the selected JDK.
9. Click "X" to close the Dynamic Code Evolution VM Installer dialog.
10. In Studio, at the right hand side of the toolbar, select Server.
11. Click Run → Edit Configurations.
12. Under Application, click Servers.
13. In VM options, add -XXaltjvm=dcevm to the end of the line.
14. Click OK.

Both instructions above are based on the info from documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\ java -jar dcevem.jar
```

It will open the DCEVM window, select the java version, and click on the install button.